# replace last number in string using regex

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace the last number in a string using `regex` and `gsub`

```
S <- "abcd2efghi2.txt"
```

The last number and the position of the last number can vary.

So I've tried the regex

```
?<=[\d+])\b
gsub("?<=[\d+])\b", "", S)
```

but that doesn't seem to work

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Always a single digit? Did you try anything? Read up on basic regex syntax?

Comment: Why would that work? Even with parentheses to make it working syntax it matches nothing, immediately followed by a non-zero number. I'd recommend trying this out in something like http://regex101.com.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with a default TRE engine using the following regex:

```
\d+(\D*)$
```

Replace with the `\1` backreference.

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(\D*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ non-digit symbols
- `$` - end of string
- `\1` -  a backreference to the Group 1 value (so as to restore the text matched and consumed with the `(\D*)` subpattern).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yKxXme/1).

[R code demo](http://ideone.com/AHjwsZ):

```
sub("\\d+(\\D*)$", "\\1", S)
## => [1] "abcd2efghi.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: If I wanted to replace the number with another number, like `1`, this regex wouldn't work right?

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/STYuEJ). All you need is to add the number, *any* text, before the backreference. You just reconstruct the matched text in the replacement: you matched 1 or more digits, then any 0+ non-digits, so, you need to keep `\1` (the non-digits), but you may add anything before and after it.

Comment: Ok, I see the idea behind `\\1` now. Appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

[`\d+(?=\D*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Cp9dkl/1)

It matches a sequence of digits when everything that follows consists of non-digits (`\D`) until the end of the string (`$`).